# how to use virtual scroll on table

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, frontend

Good morning
I implemented the "cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport" to improve the performance when loading data, but there was a break in the table where when using the virtual scroll another vertical scroll is automatically created, if anyone knows how to implement it properly I appreciate it. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you working with Material Table?

Comment: no, I'm using a library called PO UI

Comment: I put an example @abellay